# Select first element but excluding those that are inside other element

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm trying to select the first element in the body with class `.box` but excluding those inside the class `.topbar`.

I was using this approach `:not(.topbar)>.box` and is selecting *all* the elements `.box` excluding the one inside `.topbar` but I just want the first one.

I know that I can select it in an easier way but I'm wondering how could I do it that way...

**Note:** the number of elements are not fixed, so `.topbar` could exist or not...

Example:

```
<body>
    <div class="topbar">
        <div class="box">
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box"> <!-- Just want to select this one -->
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        ....
    </div>
</body>
```

Thanks!

Comment: are all the div.box elements always a direct child of body (except the one in topbar) or could they be anywhere in the DOM?

Comment: Exactly, all direct child of body

Comment: Guys I thought `body > .box:first-child { border: 1px solid red; } ` was good but that doesn't seem to work, why? [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/S5Efg/)

Comment: first-child applies if the element is the first child of its parent.  In your example above, topbar is the first child of the parent (body).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can divide this up into two cases:
1) like in your example above, topbar is the first child and box is the second child
2) if topbar doesn't exist, then box is the first child

```
.topbar + .box, body > .box:first-child {background:red;}
```

Comment: I thought that `body > .box:first-child` would work, but somehow it doesn't. Your answer seems to be the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a more robust way of doing it.

Consider a more generalized version of the original HTML snippet:

```
<div class="topbar">
    <div class="box">In the topbar...</div>
    <div class="box">In the topbar...</div>
</div>
<div>temp</div>
<div class="box">Just want to select this one...</div>
<div class="box">a second one....</div>
<div>temp</div>
<div class="box">a third one....</div>
<div>temp</div>
<div class="box">a third one....</div>
```

and apply the following CSS:

```css
body > div.box
{
    background-color: beige;
}
body > div.box ~ div.box
{
    background-color: pink;
}
```

See demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/Rufcc/

The first rule selects all the `div.box` elements that are a child of `body` and applies a background color.

The second rule then selects all the `div.box` elements after the first one and then overwrites the background-color to some default value (could be `transparent`).

The main advantage of this approach is it can pick out the first `div.box` element regardless of how many other elements are before it.

Comment: div.box is the same as div.box:nth-of-type(n)

Comment: Nice generalized version, though.

Comment: `nth-of-type` selects only by the tag name, and then filters by any classes (`.box` in this example). Originally, I was trying out `.box:nth-of-type(1)` to discover that the syntax was incorrect, and eventually discovered something that did work.  JavaScript/jQuery is needed for more generalized selectors.

Answer (score 1):

```
.topbar + .box { background:red; }
```

Comment: That one is working perfect, but not when the `.topbar` doesn't exist. At the same time you were giving me the answer I was editing my question to add the note that the `.topbar` could not exist.